# c++ if(cin>>input) doesn't work properly in while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, user-input, cin

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to solve the exercise 6 from chapter 4 out of Bjarne Stroustrups book "Programming Principles and Practise Using C++ and don't understand why my code doesn't work.

The exercise:

> Make a vector holding the ten string values "zero", "one", ...,
>   "nine". Use that in a program that converts a digit to its
>   corresponding spelled-out value: e.g., the input 7 gives the output
>   seven. Have the same program, using the same input loop, convert
>   spelled-out numbers into their digit form; e.g., the input seven gives
>   the output 7.

My loop only executes one time for a string and one time for an int, the loop seems to continue but it doesn't matter which input I'm giving, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

One time it worked for multiple int inputs, but only every second time. It's really weird and I don't know how to solve this in a different way.

It would be awesome if someone could help me out. 
(I'm also not a native speaker, so sorry, if there are some mistakes)

The library in this code is a library provided with the book, to make the beginning easier for us noobies I guess.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
   vector<string>s = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

   string input_string;
   int input_int;

   while(true)
   {
        if(cin>>input_string)
        {
             for(int i = 0; i<s.size(); i++)
             {
                  if(input_string == s[i])
                  {
                       cout<<input_string<<" = "<<i<<"\n";
                  }
             }
        }

        if(cin>>input_int)
        {
            cout<<input_int<<" = "<<s[input_int]<<"\n";
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it doesn't do what it's supposed to do` is not a useful problem description. "Hello, Chuck's auto repair? My car doesn't do what it's supposed to do".

Comment: Never, like seriously never use  `while(true)` like this. Start using `while(variable){}` instead. Is a too-bad habit that is better not to start using. Start from there, you ll figure out  the rest.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, I really had no idea how to formulate that question.

Answer (score 1):

When you (successfully) read input from `std::cin`, the input is *extracted* from the buffer. The input in the buffer is removed and can not be read again.

And when you first read as a string, that will read any possible integer input as a string as well.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Attempt to read as `int` ***first***. And if that fails [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the errors and read as a string.
2. Read as a string, and try to [convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to an `int`. If the conversion fails you have a string.

Comment: I tried both and sadly I can't get it to work.

When the conversion fails it doesn't enter the else-branch, it just ends my program :/. "Aborted (core dumped)"

I tried it with stoi(), do you have better suggestions?

Comment: @Neyeli If you read the linked `std::stoi` reference you will notice that it could throw exceptions. If you're not comfortable with exceptions then you could use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> `if(cin >> input)` doesn't work properly in while loop?

A possible implementation of the input of your program would look something like:

```
std::string sentinel = "|";
std::string input;

// read whole line, then check if exit command
while (getline(std::cin, input) && input != sentinel)
{
    // use string stream to check whether input digit or string
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    // if string, convert to digit

    // else if digit, convert to string

    // else clause containing a check for invalid input
}
```

To discriminate between `int` and `string` value you could use [peek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/), for example.
Preferably the last two actions of conversion (between `int` and `string`) are done by separate functions.

Assuming the inclusion of the headers:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
```

---